# Follow up, extreme sluggishness on machine doing IO

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, performance, io

This is a follow up to a [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/955418/consistent-100-disk-access).

After more investigation it appears that I have a slightly different problem, whenever I do any volume of disk based activity like copying files or backing up sql databases, My disk usage in task manager goes to 100% and average io response times go up to >4000ms often > 10000ms.

This slows my whole machine down to a crawl and any activity like opening a program, doing a build of our software etc slows to a crawl.

Now I have an SSD hybrid drive in the machine and that doesn't seem to have improved matters, I have done crystal disk health checking and bench marking in my previous ticket.

Is there anything I can do or do I have to put up with this.  Its my work machine and I frequently have this problem and its really irritating.

Comment: A driver problem for an input/ouput device could cause this problem  The best way to determine if you have a driver problem is to benchmark the i/o behavior and simotaniously benchmark the memory usage on drivers.  [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/175501/how-to-diagnose-a-sluggish-or-unresponsive-machine?rq=1)

Comment: How would you benchmark the memory usage on the drivers, simply using process explorer

Comment: You don't you would use other tools.  [Windows 8 extremely high disk usage and slow IO](http://superuser.com/questions/591250/windows-8-extremely-high-disk-usage-and-slow-io?rq=1)

Comment: I've had a look as I currently have IO issues due to tar running on a large file and nothing stands out in memory usage and its staying fairly constant